# What does bashrc PS1 check [ “$PS1” = “\\s-\\v\\\$ ” ] mean?

Tags: bash, bashrc

In /etc/bashrc file in Fedora/Red Hat I see following line:

```
[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

What is the check being done in `[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ]` and why is PS1 set only if the test succeeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s-\v\$␣` [is the default prompt string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables), the one Bash sets when starting interactively with `PS1` unset. It shows the basename of the shell process (usually `bash` or `sh`), the version and a dollar sign, e.g. `bash-4.4$`. (Or a `#` instead of `$` if running as root.)

The idea of appears to be to set a more useful prompt, but not if some other startup file has already set it.

The backslashes are doubled in `"\\s-\\v\\\$ "` since within a double-quoted string `\x` has a special meaning for some values of `x`. `\\` unambiguously represents a literal backslash. (Though for some reason they haven't done that on the assignment side).

Using single quoted strings would make the backslashes a bit easier to read:

```
[ "$PS1" = '\s-\v\$ ' ] && PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

The check being done is a string comparison `=`. It's comparing the value of $PS1 to the string `\s-\v\$`, where the backslashes need to be escaped in the string so that they get compared to actual backslashes instead of attempting to escape the following character.

The `&&` syntax is the part that sets PS1 only if the preceding test succeeds.

The overall logic here is apparently to update PS1 only if it was previously set to a specific value.

Comment: I understand that it is string comparison and && being used as a test. My question rather was about significance of that string and "why is PS1 set only if the test succeeds".

Comment: The poster already acknowledged that && was testing for the success of the previous command and so the answer doesn't give the required response,

Comment: I think you'd have to ask the maintainers of that file to ask *why* it is set that way.

Answer (score 1):

(I debated whether to make this an answer since it's such a swag but here ya go...)

Just a theory but the first form (e.g. `bash-3.2.1$`) looks like the prompt I often see when logged in as root or other "non-user" account . The second, overriding form (e.g. `[joeblow@myhost /tmp]$`) is more user-centric. So maybe this is to detect when going from a system account to user account...then, and only then, change to a more appropriate prompt. Otherwise assume someone would want to preserve the current prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It's an awkward way to check if `PS1` is `bash`'s default, or if it was customized by the user in `~/.bashrc` (or in any of the `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*` or `~/.bash_profile` files in the case of a login shell).

In the former case, `PS1` will be set to the ugly and annoying `[user@host last_path_elem]$`; in the latter case, it will be left as is.

Notice that on RedHat `/etc/bashrc` is sourced explicitly from the default `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` installed from `/etc/skel`; do not confuse `/etc/bashrc` with `/etc/bash.bashrc` which is sourced before `~/.bashrc` on some systems (eg. [Debian](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~doko/+junk/pkg-bash-debian/view/head:/patches/deb-bash-config.diff#L31)).

Answer (score -1):

I believe the comparison is checking to see if the shell is an interactive session. `\s-\v$` as a $PS1 var evaluates to `bash-5.0$` on my machine. See the differences here:

```
Jonathans-Air:~ lirum$ bash
bash-5.0$ echo "$PS1"
\s-\v\$
bash-5.0$ exit
exit
Jonathans-Air:~ lirum$ echo "$PS1"
\h:\W \u\$
```

Comment: Bash unsets `PS1` completely if the shell is non-interactive, so testing it against a non-empty string value doesn't really help there. Testing for empty `$PS1` is done in some places, e.g. Debian's `/etc/bash.bashrc` has `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` to exit if the shell is non-interactive.